# Optimizing MySQL aggregate functions - AVG, MIN, MAX, and STDDEV

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a tool which runs from 1 PC. It creates jobs and puts them out on beanstalk for execution by other PCs. When a job is created a row in a job_times table is created with the `JobID` and `Created` columns populated. Then when a PC grabs the job for execution the `Claimed` column is populated. Upon successful completion of the job the `Completed` column is populated. All columns, except `JobID` are populated with *nix timestamps.

I'm building some basic reporting for the tool and I can easily grab the stats using a MySQL statement like this one to determine the times between job creation and job claims:

`SELECT AVG(Claimed - Created) AS ave, STDDEV(Claimed - Created) AS std, MIN(Claimed - Created) AS min, MAX(Claimed - Created) AS max FROM job_times WHERE Claimed > 0 AND Created > 0`

I assume that in each instance of `(Claimed - Created)` MySQL is grabbing all applicable rows and doing the subtraction. So for the statement above MySQL does the subtraction of each row 4 times - once for AVG, once for STDDEV, once for MIN, and once for MAX.

First, is this assumption correct? If so, then is there a way to do the subtraction once and reuse it for each aggregate function?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you were storing the `Claimed - Created` value in another column in the table?

Comment: I tend to design my DBs so that I'm never storing the same info twice. Storing the difference would be storing data I can derive and thus, in my opinion, storing the same data twice. And since I am storing Created, Claimed, and Completed if I were to store the difference of all 3 combos I'd be roughly doubling the amount of memory this table occupied on my PC. It currently has over 100k rows and will likely grow much larger.

Comment: Having two range conditions in your `WHERE` clause, optimizing substractions is hardly what you should care about.

Comment: All right, how would you build the query then?